# why is the crystal report viewer not working at execution time

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'CrystalReportViewer1', but its type (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer).

Source Error:

Line 14:         To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
Line 15:     </p>
Line 16:     <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
Line 17:         AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" 
Line 18:         ReportSourceID="aaaaa" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" 


Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 16

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. It occurs for version problem.

See at top of the page:

Have version-10.5.3700.0, change it Version=13.0.2000.0. then it works

After that it doesn't work, then close the application & restart, you get a promt message-change for new old version to new version, click yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are install the CRforVS_13_0_2.exe then you may try to follow the below coding.


<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" %> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

hope it can help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem got resolved by changing the version from `10.5.3700.0` to `13.0.2000.0`.

thanks a lot :)